# Generate date objects in hour steps between two given dates

Tags: ruby

Given are two timestamps in the format `YYYYMMDDHH`, which are perfectly parseable by `DateTime.strptime`.

What I want to create is a list of strings in the given format from above in one hour steps, starting from the first date up to the second date.

Example input: `2013011515` and `2013011822`.

Expected output: `['2013011515','2013011516','2013011517','2013011518', ... , '2013011820', '2013011820', '2013011821', '2013011822']`

Is there any ruby library or core functionality to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step) with an hourly resolution if you use ruby 1.9:

```
date1 = DateTime.strptime('2013011522', '%Y%m%d%H')
date2 = DateTime.strptime('2013011622', '%Y%m%d%H')

date_range = date1.step(date2, 1.0/24).to_a
```

Alternatively, on ruby 1.8.7, use a loop

```
date1 = DateTime.strptime('2013011522', '%Y%m%d%H')
date2 = DateTime.strptime('2013011622', '%Y%m%d%H')

new_date = date1
date_range = [date1]
date_range << (new_date += 1.0/24) while new_date <= date2
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9 is available. Thanks for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
dt_from = "2013011515"
dt_to = "2013011822"
require 'date'
date_from = Date.parse(dt_from[0,8])
date_to = Date.parse(dt_to[0,8])
res = []
date = date_from
while (date <= date_to)
  if date == date_from
    hours = (dt_from[8,2].to_i..23).to_a
  elsif date == date_to
    hours = (0..dt_to[8,2].to_i).to_a
  else
    hours = (0..23).to_a
  end
  hours.each {|h| res << "#{date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}#{"%02d" % h}"}
  date += 1
end
puts res.inspect
```

Comment: Proper solution, but the accepted one is more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i forgot about adding fractional amounts to date/time :)

Comment: ...and this solution MAY BE more proper than the accepted one if you curious about such things as leap seconds or weird timezones